# In mlr and parallelMap it possible to parallelize multiple levels? For example mlr.tuneParams and mlr.benchmark

Tags: r, mlr

I'm running a mlr benchmark with multiple learners (around 15 different learners) with nested resampling using the irace tuning control.
My question is: is it possible to run two parallelization levels on parallelMap?

If I use the mlr.benchmark level, the faster learners end firsts and only the more computational demanding learners remain running, a single thread for each. So end up with 4 maybe 5 threads running.

If I use the mlr.tuneParams level, the irace tuning control spawns 6 threads evaluates all of them and then after all of them finish, it creates 6 others. I know that this method is sequential in nature.

My point is either way the CPU cores are not fully used.
For example if a CPU has 12 cores I could run two learners at same time with each learner using 6 cores for tuning.

Right now I'm doing this manually: I create multiple R sessions and run them separately.

Thanks!

Comment: All levels should be parallelized by default without you having to specify them. What are you doing to enable the parallelization at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot parallelize across multiple levels currently with `parallelMap`.
The `level` argument of `parallelMap::parallelStart()` only accepts a [single level](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/parallelMap/versions/1.4/topics/parallelStart).

This is a known limitation and probably won't change anymore in the future. 
In [mlr3](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3) all levels will be parallelized using the `future` package.

If you have nested calls  to `parallelMap()` in your code without setting an explicit level, the first call in the pipeline will be parallelized.